# What's the story behind the original Florida flag emblem?

Tags: flags, florida

I'm doing some research for school and a part of this is learning about the seal of the flag, my question is as following:
What's the story behind the original Florida flag emblem and the story behind the modified ones?

My previous research: In the edited ones, I see a ship a woman with flowers in her hands, a coastal place(port?), palm trees, thickets, shining sun. Looking at this I presume this is a state that has a long story with nature and agriculture.

Comment: Welcome to History.SE! What research have you performed yourself?

Comment: @F1Krazy I edited the question.

Comment: You might want to refine your question after checking these Wikipedia pages: [Flag of Florida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Florida) and [Seal of Florida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_of_Florida).

Comment: You were asked what research you have done (not what you see while looking at the seal).The goal of the school project is for **you** to learn how to research a theme. Asking **others** to do this for you does not fullfill that goal.